# Loading only 3 elements of sub-array

Tags: javascript

I am creating a html tag out of my javascript object.

I would like to add only 3 `img` elements with the properties `amzImg` and `partTitle`.

I tried the following:

```js
const results = {
  "generalInfo": [{
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

let dataSet = results.generalInfo.map((item, i) => [
  i + 1,
  `
    <img src="${item.hardware.amzImg}" alt="${item.hardware.partTitle}" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="${item.hardware.amzImg}" alt="${item.hardware.partTitle}" height="42" width="42">
    <img src="${item.hardware.amzImg}" alt="${item.hardware.partTitle}" height="42" width="42">
    <a href="${item.permalink}">
                    ${item.title}
                 </a>`,
  `$${item.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`
])

console.log(dataSet)
```

However, the above example gives me 3 elements if there are only 2 elements in my list. Like for the first hardware object the following:

```
[ 1,'\n 
<img src="undefined" alt="undefined" height="42" width="42">\n    
<img src="undefined" alt="undefined" height="42" width="42">\n    
<img src="undefined" alt="undefined" height="42" width="42">\n
<a href="http://localhost/test-title-4/">\nTest Title\n</a>',
'$331.99'
],
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I would love to  have the following output:

Comment: `I would love to have the following output:` then `return undefined;` maybe?

Comment: That's because you didn't loop over the `hardwares` in each iteration. You just built a list of images assuming you had 3 hardwares.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the array manually in each iteration by looping over the `item.hardwares`.

```js
const results = {
  "generalInfo": [{
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

let dataSet = results.generalInfo.map((item, i) => {
  // build the array manually
  var data = [i + 1];
  var html = "";
  /*item.hardware.forEach((hardware) => {
      html += `<img src="${hardware.amzImg}" alt="${hardware.partTitle}">`;
  });*/
  
  for (var i = 0, len = item.hardware.length; i < len && i < 3; i++) {
     var hardware = item.hardware[i];
     html += `<img src="${hardware.amzImg}" alt="${hardware.partTitle}">`;
  }
  
  html += `<a href="${item.permalink}">${item.title}</a>`;
  data.push(html);
  data.push(`$${item.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`);
  return data;
})

console.log(dataSet)
```

Comment: Thx for your reply!  Any suggestion how to limit the insertion via `forEach`-loop only to maximum of 3 elements?

Comment: @Anna.Klee A quick way is to use `for` loop as shown in my edit.

Comment: Thx for the update! I tried to implement it in my code, but saw that you are basically building an object instead of the needed array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to slice(0,3) your hardware array to get only 3 elements from sub array then just iterate over it to form required html string.

```js
const results = {
  "generalInfo": [{
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "post_id": 87,
    "title": "Test Title",
    "permalink": "http://localhost/test-title-4/",
    "category": [],
    "totalPrice": 331.99,
    "hardware": [{
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      },
      {
        "partCategory": "x",
        "partTitle": "Test Title",
        "amzImg": "https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }]
}

  let dataSet =   results.generalInfo.map((item, i)=>[i+1, item.hardware.slice(0,3).map(img => '<img src="'+img.amzImg+'" alt="'+img.partTitle+'"/>')])

console.log(dataSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to build the array manually, I would just create a new function that handles the images.

```
const results = {
  generalInfo: [
    {
      post_id: 87,
      title: 'Test Title',
      permalink: 'http://localhost/test-title-4/',
      category: [],
      totalPrice: 331.99,
      hardware: [
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        },
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        },
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        },
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      post_id: 87,
      title: 'Test Title',
      permalink: 'http://localhost/test-title-4/',
      category: [],
      totalPrice: 331.99,
      hardware: [
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        },
        {
          partCategory: 'x',
          partTitle: 'Test Title',
          amzImg:
            'https://images-na.ssl-images.com/images/I/51wsdfgDLUEJwCL.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const getImages = hardware =>
  hardware
    .slice(0, 3)
    .map(
      h => `<img src="${h.amzImg}" alt="${h.partTitle}" height="42" width="42">`
    )
    .join('\n');

const dataSet = results.generalInfo.map((item, i) => [
  i + 1,
  `${getImages(item.hardware)}
    <a href="${item.permalink}">
      ${item.title}
    </a>`,
  `$${item.totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`
]);

console.log(dataSet);
```